# Hiding Boostrap list-group-item

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am working on creating a live search type thing for a list-group with JQuery.

I have the search fully working and I am using hide() to hide the list-group-items that do not match the current search, however, since I am only hiding the elements, the first and last list items (in the original list) retain the first-child and last-child status, thus keeping the border radius and causing the search result list first and last items to not have the border radius unless they are one of the originals. And I was wondering what would be the best way to add border radius to the first and last-non hidden list-group-items.

Here is a bootly of what I am talking about: http://www.bootply.com/M6g7cEeRon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code below `$(".list-group-item").each(function() {});`, here is my [fiddle]..(http://jsfiddle.net/HmrJz/1/)

```
$(".list-group-item:visible").each(function(index) {
     if(index == 0){
         $(this).css("border-top-left-radius", "10px");
         $(this).css("border-top-right-radius", "10px");
     }
     if(index == $(".list-group-item:visible").length - 1){
         $(this).css("border-bottom-left-radius", "10px");
         $(this).css("border-bottom-right-radius", "10px");
     }
 });
```

Comment: That is not working and I think it has to do with the fact that last-child and first-child elements are still in the DOM, they are just hidden, which means that when the first or last are hidden this will still select them rather than the first visible one.

Comment: That works! However I needed to add $(".list-group-item").css("border-radius", "0px"); before $(".list-gorup-item).each(function() {...

Thankyou